# ContractsFinder API

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to get downloads from UK government contractsfinder API.

This is the python code I have:

```
import requests

base_url = "https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/api/rest/2/search_notices"
keyword = "analysis"


params = {
 "searchCriteria": {
"types": [
  "Contract"
],

"keyword": "Analysis",
"queryString": None,
"regions": "Wales,South East",
"publishedFrom": "01/06/2023",
"publishedTo": None,
#"deadlineFrom": null,
#"deadlineTo": null,
#"approachMarketFrom": null,
#"approachMarketTo": null,
#"awardedFrom": null,
#"awardedTo": null,
#"isSubcontract": null,
"suitableForSme": True,
#"suitableForVco": false,
#"awardedToSme": true,
#"awardedToVcse": false,
#"cpvCodes": null
  },
  "size": 1000
}

response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    # Process the retrieved data as needed
    print(data)
else:
    print("Request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
```

But it returns a 404 error. Has anyone managed to get contacts data using the API? Or is there something wrong with the API call? Not my area of expertise so I might have done something very dumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/apidocumentation/) you need a post request instead of a get request. I think the request should be the following:

```
response = requests.post(base_url, json=params)
```

As far as I can tell you also need authentication. So that means you need to pass headers into the requests function as well.

The base_url should include the MIMEtype and be the following:

```
base_url = "https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/api/rest/2/search_notices/json"
```

I would also print the response.json() when you get a 404, sometimes there is more information in the response that can help you figure out the correct request.

Comment: thanks - tried amending the response as suggested but still getting  a 404. Printing response gives <Response [404]>

Comment: I've looked at the documentation a bit more. I think you need to add a mimetype to the url. In this case the [mimetype](https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/apidocumentation/ResourceModel?modelName=MimeType) is json. 

If you change to the correct url you will at least get new errors

Comment: thanks Gustafino. I also needed to change response = requests.post(base_url, data=params) to response = requests.post(base_url, json=params) for anyone else looking to do this.

Comment: Glad you got it working! I've updated the answer to include your update and the mimetype.